# Recursive select with conditions

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

My problem is as follows:

1. I need to check if one of the values (**average**) of a select is null
2. If it is, run a select looking for the first non-null value in different period (date).
3. After this, perform an operation to check what period of (date - range), this is
4. After that do the avg

#### Human Language

I want get **average cost of all products**, *grouped by periods*.

If in the specific period, the product not have invoice, I need get the average  for the previous period (if that has an average cost).

Periods **aren't months**, they are defined by the customer and can overlap 2 months, for example:

```
2012-01-01 - 2012-01-29
2012-01-30 - 2012-02-27
```

How can I do this **in ONE query**?
The query is more or less as follows (`average` is the column that I want to compare the value):

```
select
    p.id
    ,(select 
        avg(cost)
    from 
        invoices i 
    where 
        i.product_id = p.id 
        and i.add_date between $start_date
        and $end_date
    ) as average
from
    products p;
```

#### Tables / DATA / Querys

See this gist (it's not the original database, I make this test now):
https://gist.github.com/4520123

Comment: Please write a title more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: It's ok now? Recursive select with conditions in Postgre SQL query

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.  You may think the question is clear, but most people reading do not understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edit post now. I think is good informations at the time.

Comment: Sorry, I am trained to read a lot of gibberish, but in this case I'm afraid I fail. What is the table definition? What are your intentions? Where is the recursion?

Comment: @wildplasser Calm down my friend. Tables: products / invoice_products. Recursive? I don't know, it's the question. And sorry for not be cleared... I try.

Comment: BTw, when we asked for sample data, [something like this is what we were hoping for](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39056/1) (the test setup to the left, not the impossible query to the right):

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter to my limited knowledge in sql, principally postgresql (because I always worked with MySQL), this query is from another world.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel: The alien crash-landed anyways. Pity though. :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muMcWMKPEWQ

Comment: `If in the specific period, the product not have invoice, I need get the average for the previous period` IIUC, "previous period" implies that you have the relevant periods stored somewhere in a table ? Can the periods overlap ?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, the date_period table, but that table not have connection (pk/fk) with any other table. But don't worry now, i can solve the problem and post the solution above (look please, and comment)

Comment: I don't see any DDL. Also: definitions for "invoices" and "drinks" are completely absent. Given a correct problem definition and a complete set of tables and test data, most of us could probably solve your "problem" in 5--10 min. Your own solution looks subobtimal, but at the moment I am not willing to look into it.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, I understand you, but this question it's because my work, in other words, one problem in my work. So, I cant' provide some informations because the security.

So I tried to provide as much information as possible, basing myself on a different data model. Can you understand my point? I know it's so hard to understand, but it is possible to abstract information and create something 'with their own hands', as I do when I need to solve the problem of someone here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @wildplasser For help you, I make one test database with my own hands now, and send to gist. If you have any questions, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the question using this query with help of my co-work friend. 
What I did was, I took the **last purchase (invoice)**, the specific product (drink) and calculated the average.

```
    select (sum(aux.price * aux.quantity) / sum(aux.quantity))
    from (select    inp.price, inp.quantity, prd.product, drk.drink_num, inv.add_date
                        from    invoices                                inv
            inner join invoice_products inp on inp.invoice = inv.invoice
            inner join products                 prd on prd.product = inp.product
            inner join drinks                       drk on drk.product = prd.product) aux,
    date_period dtp
    where 
            aux.add_date between dtp.starting_date and dtp.ending_date
            and aux.drink_num = 1836 -- example id
            and dtp.year <= 2012 -- current year search
    group by
            dtp.year,
            dtp.period
    order by 
            dtp.year desc,
            dtp.period desc
    limit 1
```

Anyway, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The other way to solve your problem is:

1. Find the latest month with data available.
2. Get the avg() of the month from the step one.

The query:

```
SELECT i.product_id, 
       max(date_trunc('month',i.add_date)) as last_month
FROM invoices i 
GROUP BY i.product_id
```

Will give you the last month with data available for every product.

Then:

```
SELECT p.id,
       avg(inv.cost)
FROM products p
JOIN invoices inv 
  ON inv.product_id = p.id
JOIN (SELECT i.product_id, 
             max(date_trunc('month',i.add_date)) as last_month
      FROM invoices i 
      GROUP BY i.product_id) last_inv 
  ON last_inv.product_id = inv.product_id
  AND last_inv.last_month = date_trunc('month',inv.add_date)
```

To get the `avg` of the last month.

Comment: It's a good solution Igor. I'll try run it. But in my case, the better solution is do all querys in just one query.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel You only need to run the second query. It has the first one as a sub-query. I wrote it only to explain how it works.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel: you can easily pack this into one query. Use a sub-select or a CTE. This is the superior solution because only relevant averages are computed. What you had in mind (as I read your question), a *recursive* query, computing averages is not simply possible. [I tried it and failed with `ERROR: aggregate functions not allowed in a recursive query's recursive term`.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39056/1).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks my friend. I'll try follow this solution, and your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  You want to successively check the average for different periods.  The following is an example for three periods:

```
select p.id,
       coalesce(cost_period1, cost_period2, cost_period3) as average
from products p left outer join
     (select i.product_id, 
             avg(case when i.add_date between $start_date1 and $end_date1 then cost
                 end) as cost_period1,
             avg(case when i.add_date between $start_date2 and $end_date2 then cost
                 end) as cost_period2,
             avg(case when i.add_date between $start_date3 and $end_date3 then cost
                 end) as cost_period3
      from invoices i
      group by i.product_id
     ) ip
     on p.id = ip.product_id
```

This is an untested query.  It is calculated the average for each period in the subquery, and then choosing the first non-NULL value.

Based on your comment, you just need to transform this to a separate row for each month.  Here is a typical way . . . group by year and month, then choose the most recent available.

```
select p.id, avgcost
from products p left outer join
     (select ip.*, row_number() over (partition by product_id order by yearmon desc) as seqnum
      from (select i.product_id, year(add_date)*12+month(add_date) as yearmon,
                   avg(cost) as avgcost
            from invoices i
            group by i.product_id, year(add_date)*12+month(add_date)
           ) ip
      where seqnum = 1
     ) ip
     on p.id = ip.product_id
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but isn't that, because I not have the 'excacly' period date. I need back, month after month, until find the result.